# Artifacts during drawing image from ip camera with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I connected to the IP camera and could draw image, but it's full of artifacts. I don't know why it could be, maybe i'm doing something wrong? i tried to use different codecs provided by openCV like `cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));` or any others. Examples of work: [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EYrY.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKzBR.jpg)
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLDBP.jpg)

My code:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cv::Size size = cv::Size(1920,1080);
cap.open("rtsp://172.16.16.208:554/Onvif/live/1/1");
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));
if(!cap.isOpen())
    return -1;
cvNamedWindow("Cam capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
while (cv::waitKey(30) != 27) {
    cv::Mat frame;
    if(!cap.read(frame))  break;
    cv::imshow("Cam capture", frame);
}
cap.release();
return 0;
```

How to fix it?

Comment: pictures please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I added the screenshots in the question text.

Comment: that looks like packets are dropped. issue of network or overloaded receiving computer. -- you should use a very much shorter delay to `waitKey`. just use `1`.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I Tryed it, its much better, but program crashed sometimes. I think its a bad camera. Thank you!!!!! 
Now i cant record video in file. Its not open in VLC.